# How to fix Construction Heuristic in OptaPlanner?

Tags: java, optaplanner

The solver has to deal with one Planning Entity and two Planning Variables. It assigns a TimeGrain an a Room to a Meeting. As the search space for the construction heuristic is very big I had to implement sequential move selection.

```
<constructionHeuristic>
    <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType>
    <changeMoveSelector>
      <valueSelector variableName="startingTimeGrain"/>
    </changeMoveSelector>
    <changeMoveSelector>
      <valueSelector variableName="room"/>
    </changeMoveSelector>
</constructionHeuristic>
```

The problem with that is that the solver sometimes asigns a TimeGrain which has no available rooms left, so when it's time to assign a room, the solver can't find one that doesn't break a hard constraint.

Then the local search phase is able to find a solution that does not break any hard constraint but I have to run it for a very long time to get a good solution quality. For example the solver would return distant meeting assignments even though I have a soft restriction that aims to return assignments as soon as possible.

How can I modify or optimize my construction heuristic so that it does not pick a TimeGrain that doesn't have any rooms available left?

Answer (score 0):

Usually constraints look like this:

```
when
    MyEntity(myFirstVar != null, mySecondVar != null, ...)
    ...
then ...
```

Now this rule will never match for an entity when the first var is already sequentially assigned, but the second isn't. So the first step is to only do:

```
when
    MyEntity(myFirstVar != null, ...)
    ...
then ...
```

Next, you can probably add a constraint to specifically do something like this to influence the CH:

```
when
    accumulate(
         MyEntity(myFirstVar != null, mySecondVar == null, ...)
         sum(roomUsage) > capacity
then ...
```